# How to use program.cs from startup.cs in .NET 6/7?

Tags: c#, xampp, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I try to follow a tutorial online how to integrate Flutter with an ASP.NET Core Web API, the problem is the tutorial is outdated and requires me to create an ASP.NET Core 6 instead of 5.

This is code from `startup.cs` that been deprecated in .NET 6:

```
using System;
using AutoMapper;
using fixit.Data;
using fixit.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

using System.Text;

// using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql;
// using fixit.Service;

namespace fixit
{   
    public class Startup
    {   
        readonly string AllowedOrigin = "allowedOrigin";

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("fixItConnection")));
            services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

           services.AddCors(option =>
            {
                option.AddPolicy("allowedOrigin",
                    builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader()
                    );
            });

            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddScoped<IRepository<Service>, ServiceRepository>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseCors(AllowedOrigin);
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And this is `program.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace fixit
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

I tried to write `program.cs` in .NET 6, but the app can't be built.

This is my `program.cs`:

```
using fixit.Data;
using fixit.Models;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepository<Service>, ServiceRepository>();

builder.Services.AddCors(option =>
  {
      option.AddPolicy("allowedOrigin",
          builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader()
          );
  });

var app = builder.Build();

// For production scenarios, consider keeping Swagger configurations behind the environment check
// if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
// {
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
// }

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

string connectionString = app.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AZURE_SQL_CONNECTIONSTRING")!;

try
{
    // Table would be created ahead of time in production
    using var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    conn.Open();

    var command = new SqlCommand(
        "CREATE TABLE Service (ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, servicename varchar(255), description varchar(255), category varchar(255), initialprice );",
        conn);
    using SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // Table may already exist
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}

app.MapGet("/Service", () => {
    var rows = new List<string>();

    using var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    conn.Open();

    var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Service", conn);
    using SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            rows.Add($"{reader.GetInt32(0)}, {reader.GetString(1)}, {reader.GetString(2)}");
        }
    }

    return rows;
})
.WithName("GetPersons")
.WithOpenApi();

app.MapPost("/Service", (Service person) => {
    using var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    conn.Open();

    var command = new SqlCommand(
        $"INSERT INTO Service (serviceid, servicename, description, category,initialprice,intermediateprice,advanceprice) VALUES ('{person.ServiceId}', '{person.ServiceName}','{person.Description}','{person.Category}','{person.InitialPrice}','{person.IntermediatePrice}','{person.AdvancedPrice}')",
        conn);

    using SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
})
.WithName("CreatePerson")
.WithOpenApi();

app.Run();
```

How to solve this?

Comment: You seme to have missed off many of the service registrations from your `Startup` file. It also looks like you've created a project with Minimal APIs (it's a checkbox when you create the project) whereas the `Startup` file suggests it is intended to use controllers, etc.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to piece parts of software together from different tutorials. In order to be able to do that, you actually need to understand the code and what it's doing. Else you'll probably end up breaking it. So take a step back and do one tutorial at a time until you understand every line.

Comment: P.s. after this, you should really switch to Entity Framework Core, instead of raw sql.

Comment: _"startup.cs that been deprecated in .NET 6:"_ - it was not depricated, you still are free to use generic hosting in ASP.NET Core (the one supporting `Startup`)

Comment: _"but the app can't be built."_ - And what is the error?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/openapi?view=aspnetcore-6.0), If you wanna use `.WithOpenApi()` in minimal API, You need to use `.Net 7` instead of `.Net6`.

From your code, You seem to wanna use Minimal api instead of controller Api, So when you create Web Api project with template, You can uncheck this option to create a minimal api:

[image]

Here I modified some of your code to make it executable demo, Hope it can give you some help.

**Model**

```
public class Service
    {
        public string ServiceName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public int InitialPrice { get; set; }
        public int IntermediatePrice { get; set; }
        public int AdvancedPrice { get; set; }
    }
```

**Program.cs**

```
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;


namespace MinmalApi
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            // Add services to the container.
            builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

            // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
            builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
            builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
            builder.Services.AddCors(option =>
            {
                option.AddPolicy("MyAllowSpecificOrigins",
                    builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader()
                    );
            });

            //register other service.

            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);


            string connectionString = app.Configuration.GetConnectionString("default")!;

            try
            {
                // Table would be created ahead of time in production
                using var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                conn.Open();

                var command = new SqlCommand(
                    "CREATE TABLE Service (ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, servicename varchar(255), description varchar(255), category varchar(255), initialprice int,IntermediatePrice int,AdvancedPrice int);",
                    conn);
                using SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // Table may already exist
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }


            app.MapGet("/Service", () =>
            {
                var rows = new List<string>();

                using var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                conn.Open();

                var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Service", conn);
                using SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        rows.Add($"{reader.GetInt32(0)}, {reader.GetString(1)}, {reader.GetString(2)}");
                    }
                }

                return rows;
            })
            .WithName("GetPersons");

            


            app.MapPost("/Service", (Service person) =>
            {
                using var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                conn.Open();

                var command = new SqlCommand(
                    $"INSERT INTO Service ( servicename, description, category,initialprice,IntermediatePrice,AdvancedPrice) VALUES ('{person.ServiceName}','{person.Description}','{person.Category}','{person.InitialPrice}','{person.IntermediatePrice}','{person.AdvancedPrice}')",
                    conn);

                using SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            })
            .WithName("CreatePerson");

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

**Gif Demo**

[image]

From the gif demo you can see that all endpoints are working fine.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this it worked for me**

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<UnitTestDbContext>(opt=>

{
    opt.UseSqlServer(

        builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlConnectionString"));
});
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**